# Apache FTPS Client storeFile to windows FTPS server from Unix/Linux/Max issue

Tags: java, apache, ssl, ftp, ftps

i have an issue transferring files to Windows FTP server from Unix/Mac/Linux env.

while the exact same java code works from windows pc.
 from *Nix/Mac the transfer only worked with this commands on the ftp session

```
set ftps:initial-prot 
set ftp:ssl-force true
set ftp:ssl-protect-data true
set ssl:verify-certificate no
```

while on my windows machine i didnt need them - i assume it relates to system variable.

This is my java code

```
protected FTPClient getClient(DeliveryDetails details) {
    return new FTPSClient(false); // the connection is Explicit
}

public void setClient(FTPClient client, DeliveryDetails details) throws Exception {
    client.setConnectTimeout(10000);
    client.setDefaultTimeout(1000 * 60 * 2);
    client.setControlKeepAliveTimeout(300);
    client.setDataTimeout(15000);
    client.connect(ftpDetails.host, ftpDetails.port);
    client.setBufferSize(1024 * 1024);
    client.login(ftpDetails.username, ftpDetails.getSensitiveData());
    client.setControlEncoding("UTF-8");
    client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
    client.setFileTransferMode(FTP.BLOCK_TRANSFER_MODE);
    FTPSClient ftpsClient = (FTPSClient) client;
    ftpsClient.execPBSZ(0);
    ftpsClient.execPROT("P");
    // both with it and without it didnt work ftpsClient.setWantClientAuth(false);
}

public void saveToServer(FTPClient client, File fileName, InputStream stream){
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(stream);
    boolean isSaved = client.storeFile(filename, bis);
    client.logout();
}
```

‌What is equivalent of this parameters  in the FTPS Apache class ?

```
set ftps:initial-prot 
set ftp:ssl-force true
set ftp:ssl-protect-data true
set ssl:verify-certificate no
```

Comment: 1) What is `set ftps:initial-prot` and the others? Are these `lftp` commands? Do not make us guess! Tell us! 2) What does the code do on Mac and *nix? Tell us! Exact error message, log file, anything!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that Windows NT does not support writing data in **FTP.BLOCK_TRANSFER_MODE**

Easy fix is

```
    private static final String WINDOWS_NT_SYTEM_TYPE = "Windows_NT";
   ....
   ....
    try {
            String res = client.getSystemType();
            if (res.equals(WINDOWS_NT_SYTEM_TYPE)) {
                client.setFileTransferMode(FTP.STREAM_TRANSFER_MODE);
            } else {
                client.setFileTransferMode(FTP.BLOCK_TRANSFER_MODE);
            }
        }
```